# Rails deployment. "This method may not be used" response on PUT or DELETE request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, http, put

I have a Rails 3.2 application.
Locally everything works just fine.

But when I try to make PUT or DELETE request on staging, the request status is '501 Not Implemented', and the response says '**This method may not be used**.' (GET and POST requests work well).

There are no any records about these requests in the server logs.

Does anybody know what might cause such problem?

Comment: Are you using https in these requests?

Comment: What server, VPS and SO are you using?

Comment: Can you edit the question and show some related code?

Comment: no https, just plain http, server Puma, OS - Linux CentOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
The problem was that I had a redirecting made by [pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound), which redirected the user from port 80 to port 3000, so that I don't need to specify port in address line.